# Updating highcharts gauge with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, syntax, highcharts

I finally have a Gauge looking the way I want it and I'm trying to update it with JSON from Thingspeak.  When I examine the page, I see there is an uncaught ReferenceError - data is not defined.

Sample page is [here.](http://www.sesupply.co.nz/test2.htm)  I also have it on jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SESupply/0dpk0aqf/22/)

This is the bit of the code that seems to be wrong:

```
// Add some life
 function (chart) {
     setInterval(function () {
         $(function () {
             $.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/45473/feed/last.json?api_key=N12T3CWQB5IWJAU9');
             var p;
             p = data.field2;
             if (p) {
                 newVal = p;
             }
             var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
             point.update(newVal);
         }, 3000);
     });

 });
```

});

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a callback function for $.getJSON, and the input param for that is your 'data'. 
Try this:

```
 $.getJSON(
     'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/45473/feed/last.json?api_key=N12T3CWQB5IWJAU9', 
      function (data) {
                 var p;
                 p = data.field2;
                 if (p) {
                     newVal = p;
                 }
                 var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                 point.update(newVal);
             });

         }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it seems to have sorted out my inability to code :-), BUT - now when I look at the console I get the following error:

Comment: GET https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/45473/feed/last.json?api_key=N12T3CWQB5IWJAU9 net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCESk.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.js:8630n.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:8166n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:8311n.extend.getJSON @ jquery.js:8294(anonymous function) @ test2.htm:233j @ jquery.js:3099k.add @ jquery.js:3145n.fn.ready @ jquery.js:3378n.fn.init @ jquery.js:2821n @ jquery.js:76(anonymous function) @ test2.htm:232

I have no idea what this means - could you maybe shed some light?

Comment: It looks like and issue, related with cors problem. I mean that you load json from different domain then your chart exists. Try to use a jsonp.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0dpk0aqf/28/ looks like the API has CORS enabled ... the fiddle works fine.

Comment: @Sebastian - Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I have no idea how to do that.